# optionals vs null-safe types?

Tags: null, option-type, nullable

2 different approaches to solving the billion dollar mistake. To me the former seems very verbose (and thus highly inferior), yet some languages (e.g. Rust or Haskell) chose to enforce it by completely removing null. Why? What advantages do optionals have over null-safe typing?

Comment: I don’t get the distinction.  Haskell has null-safe types since they can’t be null.

Comment: How did Haskell _remove_ null?  You’re adding the unneeded premise that there was some null value there to begin with.  Null is just a sentinel value for a reference that points to nothing, and you don’t care about references in Haskell, only values (whether the values are implemented as pointers to values or not is an implementation detail).

Comment: @Guildenstern With null-safe types i meant explicit nullability, such as `String` vs `String?` in Kotlin.

Maybe "remove" was the wrong word and i should have said "not implemented" instead.

Answer (score 0):

[I have asked the same question on r/ProgrammingLanguages and got some useful answers](https://new.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/comments/hy6emx/explicit_nullability_vs_optionals/)

TLDR: Optionals can be nested

Let's say we have a `Map<int, Optional<string>>` and look up a key. the return value would be of type `Optional<Optional<string>>`. If the outer optional is empty then the key wasn't found, and if the inner optional is empty then the key was found but mapped to an absent value.

If however we use nullability `Map<int, String?>` then this distinction becomes impossible as we simply get `null` in both cases, requiring us to make a second lookup like `myMap.containsKey()`